# "Recently Closed Tabs" in google chrome new beta version?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Earlier there was a "Recently Closed Tabs" section in sidebar of google chrome browser which shows the "links of websites" tabs which are closed recently.

Yesterday I have updated to [new beta version](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) of google chrome to check out the [themes](https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/index.html) functionality, but I am not seeing the " Recently closed tabs" section in beta version anywhere, is there any settings which I need to enable to see that section??

Comment: Version numbers?

Comment: Google Chrome 3.0.195.6

Answer (score 2):

When I open a new tab in Chrome Beta beneath the thumbnails is a section called **Recent Activities** which shows pages I had open recently.

[image]

If you're not seeing this click the triangle button at the top right of the new tab page and select "Show recent activities" from the menu.

[image]

Comment: You can also right click on any tab and select re-open closed tab to get to that same page.