# How to hide recently open history in Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm pretty new to Chrome; I only used it to debug CSS and javascripts.

I recently updated my Chrome browser a couple of week ago. Previously browsed sites start displaying in the middle of the browser.

Is there are anyway to hide previously browsed sites?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this question's answer should help you http://superuser.com/questions/27667/recently-closed-tabs-in-google-chrome-new-beta-version?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound I could not find the setting the answer has stated. It might be for old Chrome browser.

Comment: I linked you to the wrong question about the wrong new feature.  I aplogize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but it involves installing a (free) plugin to chrome called [click and clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en-GB). Just install it to chrome through the store.

After you add it, click the short cut made on your browser, go to options, scroll down to Extra then check the box which asks you to prevent access to the default history page.

If that doesn't work, another option is trying to browse using private browsing tools which prevents the browser from remembering your browsing history,it works well on Safari browser.

Comment: We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read.Also keep an eye on proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your browse history: `Ctrl + H`, *Clear browsing data...*, check *download history* and *from beginning of times* and it should do it.

Also in your case, you may want to use the incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

use this may help
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-most-visited-pages-r/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil

*sometime not working for latest chrome*

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need plugins or anything like that.  I don't care if there is search history, I just don't want that column showing porn sites... especially if I'm streaming and sharing my screen....  Not because embarrassment or anything, but because it's supposed to be family friendly....

The best way, is to just set your start page to https://www.google.com

That way it still starts with Google, but doesn't have the default open page history beneath it.  :-)

Chuck
Maverick's Arcade (on YT)